# Compare Function and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sorting, delphi-2009, callback

Assume a multi-threaded environment and a (properly synchronized) class that has one particular procedure

```
procedure SortKeyList (KeyList : TList <Integer>; Inverted : Boolean);
```

that takes a list of keys and sorts it. The procedure uses the RTL quicksort implementation TList.Sort:

```
KeyList.Sort (TComparer <Integer>.Construct (CompareKeys))
```

Now for the problem: CompareKeys has to access some members of the class in order to sort the list (that's the whole point about this class). But the RTL requires CompareKeys to be a normal function. How can I pass data from the object to the CompareKeys function in a thread-safe manner? Obviously using global exchange variables isn't an option since it is in no way thread-safe.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you're passing `CompareKeys` to `TComparer.Construct` means that `CompareKeys` *doesn't* have to be a normal function. Delphi 2009 introduced *method references*, which can refer to ordinary functions, methods, and anonymous methods. I assume `TComparer.Construct` constructs a method reference out of the ordinary function you give it. (I'm not sure why, though; I thought the compiler did that conversion automatically.)

Suppose you have a three-argument function that receives a list and the two items to compare:

```
function CompareKeys(List: TList<Integer>; Item1, Item2: Integer): Integer;
```

You should be able to pass an anonymous method something like this:

```
KeyList.Sort(function(Item1, Item2: Integer): Integer;
  begin
    Result := CompareKeys(KeyList, Item1, Item2);
  end);
```

Comment: +1 great answer. Anonymous methods with their capability to access the calling context give me exactly what I need! Haven't thought of that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use a `threadvar` (thread local variable) to hold a reference to your instance which could then be accessed from the CompareKeys function (assign the threadvar just before calling Sort).